# Why doesn't it return a value?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    public String xyz(){
        String name="stack";
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t=new Test();
        t.xyz(); //this should stack isn't it??
    }
}
```

Comment: You gotta print what the method returns!!!

Comment: It *does* return a value.  But you don't do anything with it.

Comment: System.out.println(t.xyz());

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do `t.xyz()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method does return a value (of type `String`), but your code discards it.

```
t.xyz(); // This calls the method and discards the return value
```

If you want to see the return value, assign it to a variable and print it out:

```
String str = t.xyz();
System.out.println(str);
```